# Team Foundation Server API using Oauth provided by Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, tfs, oauth, azure-active-directory, tfs-sdk

I am trying to write an application that will get an Oauth token and communicate with TFS through the API.
I've registered an application (https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com) and can get an Oauth token with the scopes that I need.

This question has a response from someone at Microsoft asking "Is one of the accounts backed by Azure Active Directory by chance?"

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9061abf8-7ee9-452f-99f1-2a84f8c16d85/vso-api-oauth2-and-multiple-vso-accounts?forum=TFService

This is the exact behavior I'm experiencing too.  I can get a token and talk to my personal TFS instance, but when I try to communicate with the AD backed TFS I get a 401.

I did try to use the AD Oauth, but it does not have the scopes for VSO. (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/)

Does anyone know how I can make API calls to a TFS server using Oauth from Azure AD?

Comment: What's your detail mean of "AD backed TFS"?  When you say it's talk to my personal TFS instance, are you using the vsts such as ((https://xxx.visualstudio.com) or on-primse TFS(http://xx:8080/TFS)?

Comment: I'm using a hosted solution of TFS (so the url is xxx.visualstudio.com).  I used the term "AD backed TFS" because it was was used by a comment in the response from a MS employee in this question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9061abf8-7ee9-452f-99f1-2a84f8c16d85/vso-api-oauth2-and-multiple-vso-accounts?forum=TFService

Comment: Based on my test, I get the same result, the access token can access all VSTS in Visual Studio Team Services Account section (Account Information page) but get 401 result if I access the VSTS with same access token, which in Accounts In Other Organizations section. In addition, I can't use the same alternative account to access this VSTS.

Answer (score 1):

Even with the same user account(email address), Microsoft account(MSA) and Azure AD(AAD) account has separate identities in the system. So the access token for them should be different.

Take my account as example:
[image]
I have a personal VSTS account with MSA(Microsoft account) and an AAD account with(devtoolssupport). When I sign in to "devtoolssupport" and perform an OAuth auth, the authorized application is only listed in "devtoolssupport", it isn't applicable for "Microsoft account". So auth the app with "Microsoft account", you need to select "Microsoft account" on this page and then perform an OAuth auth again.

Comment: So, how do I do this problematically?  A user will come to https://<mydomain>.com and that site will do a challange to either https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signedin if using the VSTS Oauth or to  login.microsoftonline.com/ if using the Azure AD.   I want to do a challenge for the VSTS OAuth token and give a resource for visualstudio.com, but that fails.

Comment: Except that doesn't help the actual TFS addin for visual studio OR the web UI.